# List field: translated values are not translated

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n

In my Drupal 8 project I have some list fields. For example maybe a field "project type" with the following key|values, coming from the original language German:

```
1 -> öffentliches Projekt
2 -> privates Projekt
```

Which I translated in the field's settings:

```
1 -> public project
2 -> private project
```

The field is NOT set to be translatable because the value should not be changed in a translation: the project type is in all languages the same! But now when I go to the node edit page, when I view the node or when I add this field as exposed filter to views I always see the German values of the field no matter what is set as the current language of the page. When I change the field to be translatable the value of the list field can be changed in English translation -> so it can come that a project is "public" in German and "private" in English what is not the desired result.

How do I get the translated values of a list field to be used in form element and node view when the list field itself should not be translatable?

Comment: You always enter the English strings/labels only in the field config, then display the form at least once in German, and after that go to interface translation and translate them to German. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that it was just a weird cache thing. I cleared the cache several times after changing these translations. Now the translated values of the select list appear without setting the field to be translatable.